# ssh into aws EC2 instance when ssh is blocked by admin

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, stunnel

I have a new aws EC2 instance, everything worked fine from home. Now the ssh access is blocked in university! I wanted to know how I can bypass that and ssh into my ec2 instance. What ways i can do it? Also, How can I use stunnel to do this? A short explanation is appreciated along with the solution.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific on how they're blocking you from the university before someone can help. Additionally, there are generally good reasons why they wouldn't want it working from anywhere but your home. Make sure you understand why they put those limitations there in the first place so you don't compromise the security of your servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following:

- Move the SSH listener on the EC2 instance to a port other than 22/tcp, like 2222/tcp.  They may just be blocking that specified port number on the firewall.
- If they're using deep packet inspection, moving the port won't help as the firewall will still detect an SSH handshake and block it.  In that case you'll need an stunnel-style solution to encrypt the handshake itself.

If they are using deep packet inspection I would recommend following these instructions:
http://www.terranpro.org/Tunnel%20SSH%20over%20SSL%20or%20HTTPS.html

An stunnel solution has a lot of moving parts:

- RSA key generation (using openssl)
- Stunnel server configuration (on EC2 side)
- Proxytunnel installation (on SSH client)

Plus you're also double-encrypting everything, so performance will suffer.  Best of luck!

Answer (score -2):

The port 22 which is used for SSH must be blocked. You need to take permission from university admin to open it on you machine.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I am asking how to use stunnel (or some other tool) to ssh into the aws instance.